# Closures: What is a good use case example? Why not a functor? And is it worth the negatives?

Tags: python, ruby, closures, functor

I recently dove into Python. Previous, I had programmed mostly numerical and data analysis code in C++ and Matlab. I saw a lot of discussions about Python and Ruby and closures. Almost all examples looked like this:

```
>>> def makeAdder(y):
...  def myAdder(x):
...   return x + y
...  return myAdder
... 
>>> f = makeAdder(10)
>>> f(5)
15
```

I understand that this can be useful in some sense. However, realistically, the behavior in situations like this ('read only' situations as it were) can easily be emulated by an object (a functor):

```
>>> class MyAdder(object):
...  def __init__(self,y):
...   self.y = y
...  def __call__(self,x):
...   return self.y + x
... 
>>> f = MyAdder(5)
>>> f(10)
15
```

The object doesn't take up substantially more space to code, and it is far more versatile. It's also much easier to track and debug subsequent code.

In this case, we only read from the nonlocal variable. But we can also write to it: in Ruby, naturally, in Python by using the nonlocal keyword. The object supports that as well of course. But with the object, you have the data bundled together so you know exactly what's going on. The closure can potentially be carrying around variables in a totally non-transparent way and this can lead to code that's amazingly hard to debug. Here's a really bizarre example:

```
irb(main):001:0> def new_counter
irb(main):002:1> x = 0
irb(main):003:1> lambda { x +=1 }
irb(main):004:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):005:0> counter_a = new_counter
=> #<Proc:0x00007f85c6421cd0@(irb):3>
irb(main):006:0> counter_a.call
=> 1
irb(main):007:0> counter_a.call
=> 2
```

At least to me, this behavior is unintuitive. It also has the potential to cause memory leaks. This gives you a huge amount of rope to hang yourself with. Again, this is especially true in Ruby where you do not need to enable this explicitly (unlike Python), and because in Ruby one has blocks all over their main code, which have access to everything. If an outside variable gets changed as a result of being in a closure, if you pass that closure around you can have a variable changed indefinitely far and out of scope from the place where it lives. Contrast to an object that always safely carries its data with it.

Why do you hear a lot of talk about how good closures are, and how they should be potentially included in Java, how it sucked when they weren't fully in Python, etc. ? Why not use a functor? Or refactor the code to avoid, given how incredibly dangerous they can be? Just to clarify, I'm not one of those foaming at the mouth OO types. Have I underestimated their use, overstated their danger, or both?

Edit: maybe I should distinguish between three things: closures that only read once (which is what my example shows, and almost everyone discusses), closures that read in general, and closures that write. If you define a function inside another function using a variable local to the outer function, there's almost no chance this will come back to haunt you. The variable in that space is not accessible in any way I can think of, so you can't change it. This is pretty safe, and a convenient (possibly more than functors) way to generate functions.
On the other hand, if you create a closure inside a class method or inside the main thread, it will read in variables each time that are called that can be accessed from other places. So it can change. I think this is dangerous because the closed over variable does not appear in the function header. You could have say a long closure on page 1 of your code that closes over a main thread variable x, and then modify x for unrelated reasons. Then re-use the closure and get bizarre behavior you don't understand, which may be hard to debug.
If you actually write to enclosed variables, then as my example with Ruby shows you really have the potential to make a mess and cause unexpected behavior.

Edit2: I gave an example of bizarre behavior from closures for the third usage, writing to non local variables. Here's an example of bizarre (not as bad) behavior from the second usage (defining closures in scopes where their closed-over variables can be modified):

```
>>> fs = [(lambda n: i + n) for i in range(10)]
>>> fs[4](5)
14
```

Comment: I don't know Ruby, so I don't know if your claim of memory leaks is realistic.  It isn't an issue in Python, maybe you could clarify that point?

Comment: Agreed, particularly I don't know where *incredibly dangerous* comes from.

Comment: I think it mostly comes down to Python is not C++, Ruby is not C++, JavaScript is not C++, Perl is not C++, ... If you try to use functors everywhere then people will be wondering why you're trying to write C++ in Python. I'd probably say that functors are a kludge or implementation detail for languages that don't have GC and  closures, a kludge that more dynamic languages (usually) don't need. And why define a whole new class when you don't need all that machinery?

Comment: So, from my example with unintuitive Ruby behavior, you can see that a variable is being kept open that one would not expect. You can expand this into a slightly more detailed example, such as given here: https://practicingruby.com/articles/shared/mvzhovpjbghr. To be honest, my Ruby is pretty limited and I do not fully understand it. However, I can tell that you can rewrite my example using Python (and nonlocal) and it behaves the exact same way. So I suspect the same memory leak issues could occur.

Comment: It's not really a memory leak - that variable will only be kept around while the returned function is kept in scope, and there is no reason to believe that will be longer than needed.

Comment: You seem to have asked this question in the mindset of "closures are bad", and are trying to find ways to show that to be the case. Yes, there are bad uses for closures, but that doesn't make them inherently bad.

Comment: I don't necessarily think they're bad, I'm just comparing the potential upside to the potential downside. Some of the code I posted has incredibly bizarre behavior in a very simple example. It would not be fun funding a bug of similar nature in a large, complicated piece of code. As I said, when the closure is defined in a function, it's much safer. Otherwise, you can have strange stuff happening. And since the same functionality can be provided by another construct, the fact that it's a tiny bit more verbose doesn't seem so bad.

Comment: An example of a good use case for the second or third scenario is still lacking.

Comment: First-class functions, lambda expressions (anonymous functions) and also closures are widely used where available. Everyone will tell you they are a great thing. This alone should be good evidence that they give more benefit than harm. You can use every tool to do stupid things. Just use it to do the good things only. Macros in C can do horrible stuff and prevent good tool support for the language. But sometimes they are the right tool. I'd bet on closures having a better balance...

Answer (score 10):

Readability. Your Python example shows how much more obvious and easy to read the closure version is compared to the functor.

We also neatly avoid making a class that does nothing but act like a function - this smells of redundancy.

If nothing else, when we are *doing* something, [it makes sense to describe it as an action, not an object](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.co.uk/2006/03/execution-in-kingdom-of-nouns.html).

As another note, an example of where these structures are used a *lot* in Python, to great effect, is decorators. Most function decorators do something like this, and they are a really useful feature.

Edit: As a note on state, remember that functions are not special in Python, they are still objects:

```
>>> def makeAdder(y):
...     def myAdder(x):
...         return x + myAdder.y
...     myAdder.y = y
...     return myAdder
... 
>>> f = makeAdder(10)
>>> f(5)
15
>>> f.y
10
```

Comment: I think that's a matter of taste.  I personally agree, but I've encountered lots of people who find the idea of functions returning functions to be difficult to grasp, because they have trouble getting their head around when the outer vs inner functions are called.

Comment: @BrenBarn Given Python's dynamic nature, the idea that functions are first order objects is a pretty central one, and I don't see that classes acting like functions is an easier concept. Not to say I don't see your point, but I don't think it really counts against them.

Comment: I think one can ask whether it is really genuinely more readable. After all: this is not just a function, it also has state. Additionally, if you ever need to check anything about the state later on, it's much easier with an object.

Comment: @NirFriedman Are you implying all functions don't have state? If you need to check the state from another context, then maybe your example has outgrown closures, yes, but that doesn't make them bad. Remember this isn't Java, we don't need to worry about being consistent with how we implement it, we can change that later if we find we need to. See also my edit.

Comment: Latty, I mean more that functions in a traditional sense do not have state, not that the specific implementation of functions in Python cannot have state.
It just seems like if we are going to be carrying around state, why not explicitly make it clear that we are carrying it around? My class version was just one extra line of code compared to the functional version.
Overall though, I'm bothered more by using closures in other cases, see my Edit to the original question.

Comment: @NirFriedman Is there a reason that just because functions in other languages don't offer this functionality, we should avoid it in Python? Other than that, you are no longer talking about closures in general. Yes, there are cases where closures are not the best option. You seem to be changing your question to exclude use cases until there are no good ones left.